TypeError while importing from ydata-profiling
Getting TypeError while trying to import from ydata-profiling. Reinstalling the module and reinstalling Python didn't solve the error.
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 6
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 import scipy.stats as stats
----> 6 from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
      7 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      8 import seaborn as sns

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\__init__.py:14
     10 warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=NumbaDeprecationWarning)
     12 import importlib.util  # isort:skip # noqa
---> 14 from ydata_profiling.compare_reports import compare  # isort:skip # noqa
     15 from ydata_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator  # isort:skip # noqa
     16 from ydata_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport  # isort:skip # noqa

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\compare_reports.py:12
     10 from ydata_profiling.model import BaseDescription
     11 from ydata_profiling.model.alerts import Alert
---> 12 from ydata_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
     15 def _should_wrap(v1: Any, v2: Any) -> bool:
     16     if isinstance(v1, (list, dict)):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:53
     48 from ydata_profiling.utils.paths import get_config
     50 logger = ProfilingLogger(name="ReportLogger")
---> 53 @typechecked
     54 class ProfileReport(SerializeReport, ExpectationsReport):
     55     """Generate a profile report from a Dataset stored as a pandas `DataFrame`.
     56 
     57     Used as is, it will output its content as an HTML report in a Jupyter notebook.
     58     """
     60     _description_set = None

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\_decorators.py:147, in typechecked(target)
    145 for key, attr in target.__dict__.items():
    146     if is_method_of(attr, target):
--> 147         retval = instrument(attr)
    148         if isfunction(retval):
    149             setattr(target, key, retval)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\_decorators.py:75, in instrument(f)
     72                 else:
     73                     level += 1
---> 75 module_code = compile(module_ast, f.__code__.co_filename, "exec", dont_inherit=True)
     76 new_code = module_code
     77 for name in target_path:
TypeError: required field "ctx" missing from Subscript


I'm guessing you have mismatched versions for either ydata_profiling or typeguard; however, you don't provide details for either here? What does %conda list run inside the current notebook tell you for each of those? And how well do the release dates match so that you can determine which one needs updating?

Thank you! It was typeguard version fault, update helped.

My guess, given the traceback, was mismatched versions for either ydata_profiling or typeguard.
OP said it was typeguard and update fixed it.
For investigating that I had suggested originally that helped get to there:

I'm guessing you have mismatched versions for either ydata_profiling or typeguard; however, you don't provide details for either here? What does %conda list run inside the current notebook tell you for each of those? And how well do the release dates match so that you can determine which one needs updating?

